# Xamarin.Forms Webview custom renderer for MacOS and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, macos, webview, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app that has a Webview where loads a Web App (pdfjs) to display PDF.

I've made custom renderers for UWP, Android and iOS, following official docs and it's working OK, but now I target also MacOS and WPF backends and I don't know how to make custom renderers for them (Webview).

I can't find any examples. How could I achieve this?

Thank you.